# How to open the pdf at that URL in a new tab when I click a button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a URL that comes to me from the backend. When I open this URL a pdf is loaded automatically. I don't want the pdf to be loaded automatically. I want to open the pdf at that URL in a new tab when I click a button. How can I do this in React?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a component that renders this, maybe pass the link through properties

```
const PDFLink = props => (
  <a href={props.link} target="_blank">
    Link to PDF
  </a>
);
```

Comment: I tried this, when I use it like this, it opens a new tab and loads immediately. I just want it to be seen, not downloaded.

Comment: Got it! 
You have 2 ways

- Leave to the user decide (you can change this behavior in chrome, go to chrome://settings/content/pdfDocuments to change the settings)

- Embed a pdf viewer in your website

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf this package seems to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use a special `_blank` parameter/attribute for it:

`window.open("pdf_url", '_blank');`

When you use an `<a>` anchor tag with link in your code:

`<a href="pdf_url" target="_blank">Open</a>`